# Time Slot Booking Script - Check availability

Tags: php, mysql

Trying to make a basic booking system where by a user can say they need a 30 minute appointment and the code can output what time slots are free to book for 30 minutes.

I first tried to ignore the "time" factor and code this by "slots" to take all the date time complexity out of it, and started with just making it work for 1 day.

I divided the day up into 15 minute slots and then created a $slotstatus of 1 for busy and 0 for free.

Then was a simple matter of looking through the table rows to find free slots and echo them.

The problem I have is when the time required takes more than 1 slot. SO I then need to count the amount of "Slotstatus = 0" and ensure there is enough available time for the requirement.

I tried using a count ++ when I see a 0 but then had problems on the areas where I needed to output two slots in sequence.

Im very amateur at code and im doing this as a bit of a hobby to boost my coding logic brain which is poor.

Please can someone point me in the right direction

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

```
    $count = 0;
    $req = 3;
    echo $req . " is the SlotReq<br>";
    echo $count . " is the starting count<br><br>";




$sql = "SELECT slotnumber, slottime, slotstatus FROM timeslots";
$result = $conn->query($sql);


if ($result->num_rows > 0) 
    {
        // output data of each row
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc() ) 
            {
                    if ($row["slotstatus"] == 0)
                    {
                        $count ++;

                            if ( $count == $req)
                            {


                                echo "<br>Pass for " . $row["slottime"] . " 
    Status: ". $row["slotstatus"] . " Count " . $count;


                                $count = 0; 
                            }
                            else 
                            {
                            echo "<br> False for " . $row["slottime"] . " 
    Status: ". $row["slotstatus"] . " Count " . $count; 



                            }
                    }   
                    else
                    {
                        echo "<br> False for " . $row["slottime"] .  " 
    Status: ". $row["slotstatus"] . " Count " . $count;
                        $count = 0;

                    }       
            }

    }
   else 
    {
        echo "Error: No results Found";
    }
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
```

should look like this on the page

Table 
[table as image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tjVJX.png)
ID     slottime    slotstatus
1       10:15          0
2       10:30          1
3       10:45          0
4       11:00          0
5       11:15          0
6       11:30          0
7       11:45          1

So if the user wants a 30 minute slot they should be presented with the options based on the table above as

10:45
11:00
11:15

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a query like this. It count first the free slots and the you
can query the requested slots in the outer SELECT:

```
SELECT * from (
SELECT ts.*
            , @sclotcount := IF( ts.`slotstate` = 1, 0, @sclotcount +1 ) as freeslots
    FROM timeslots ts
    CROSS JOIN ( SELECT @sclotcount := 0) as init
    ORDER by id DESC
) as result
WHERE freeslots >= 3 -- request slots
ORDER by id;
```

**SAMPLE**

```
MariaDB [test]> SELECT * from ( SELECT ts.*, @sclotcount := IF( ts.`slotstate` = 1, 0, @sclotcount +1 ) as freeslots FROM timeslots ts CROSS JOIN ( SELECT @sclotcount := 0) as init ORDER by id DESC ) as result WHERE freeslots >= 3  ORDER by id;
+----+----------+-----------+-----------+
| id | slottime | slotstate | freeslots |
+----+----------+-----------+-----------+
|  1 | 00:00:00 |         0 |         3 |
| 10 | 02:15:00 |         0 |         3 |
| 14 | 03:15:00 |         0 |         7 |
| 15 | 03:30:00 |         0 |         6 |
| 16 | 03:45:00 |         0 |         5 |
| 17 | 04:00:00 |         0 |         4 |
| 18 | 04:15:00 |         0 |         3 |
| 22 | 05:15:00 |         0 |        75 |
| 23 | 05:30:00 |         0 |        74 |
| 24 | 05:45:00 |         0 |        73 |
...
| 83 | 20:30:00 |         0 |        14 |
| 84 | 20:45:00 |         0 |        13 |
| 85 | 21:00:00 |         0 |        12 |
| 86 | 21:15:00 |         0 |        11 |
| 87 | 21:30:00 |         0 |        10 |
| 88 | 21:45:00 |         0 |         9 |
| 89 | 22:00:00 |         0 |         8 |
| 90 | 22:15:00 |         0 |         7 |
| 91 | 22:30:00 |         0 |         6 |
| 92 | 22:45:00 |         0 |         5 |
| 93 | 23:00:00 |         0 |         4 |
| 94 | 23:15:00 |         0 |         3 |
+----+----------+-----------+-----------+
80 rows in set (0.001 sec)

MariaDB [test]>
```

Comment: Just trying to make this work with my VERY limited MYSQL knowledge, Cross join, does this imply I have a separate table called ts like the one above with freeslots?
or am i being stupid?

Comment: **FROM timeslots ts** means only that ts is a alias for the table name timeslots. its only a shorter notation. so you can write ts.fieldname instead of timeslots.fieldname . **CROSS JOIN** is only a helper (in this case) to initialize the user variable ** sclotcount**.. if you not initialize you cant add like **@sclotcount +1**

Comment: You can direcly run this query on your server

Comment: THANK you that worked like a dream, I dont know why but it didnt even cross my mind to do all of the calculation on MYSQL query.